# Using flex-box-model, I couldn't align the flex-item to left and right

Tags: html, css

I have the HTML like I mentioned below...

```
<div class="parent-div">
  <div class="left-div">left side</div>
  <div class="second-left-div">left side</div>
  <div class="right-div">right side</div>
  <div class="second-right-div">right side</div>
</div>
```

...and I want to display the `left-div` in left most and `right-div` in right most. For this I am using `flex` box model (below I  have mentioned the CSS) but its not working for me.

```
   .parent-div {
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -moz-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
    }

    .left-div {
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;    
        min-width: 0;
        align-self: flex-start;
    }

    .second-left-div {
       align-self: flex-start;
    }

    .right-div, .second-right-div {
        align-self: flex-end;
    }
```

Could anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

**Why it does not work**
With the `align-self` property you can only set the individual alignment for the item overriding the `align-items` property. The alignment does not have an impact on the sequence of the output.
Short: the property does not change the sequence of the output (div containers, items).

**Solution**
To use another order than the given one (in source) you can use the `order` property.

**Links**
See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/6ytv43pn/1/ 
Reference: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Thank you Muller. But as I mentioned I have to display the `right-div` and `second-right-div` in right most corner which equals to `float: right`. But since we are using `flex` container `float:right` wont' work.

Comment: In my sample you can see how you do it with the 'order' property. Just see the link http://jsfiddle.net/6ytv43pn/1/

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, but not fair enough to me :(

Link: http://jsfiddle.net/z1g13fwo/

Here the problem is, when we resize the browser left most divs(`left-div` and `second-left-div`) getting override. But I don't want it to override.

What I expect here is, when we resize the browser if I don't have enough space to display (both) left div's(`left-div` and `second-left-div`) then I need to show the `ellipsis` for `second-left-div` and (on further resize) if I don't have the space for `left-div` then I need to show the `ellipsis` for `left-div`.

Comment: I understand now what you want to achieve - I misunderstood your intention at first. You could do this with media queries.